# Render condition

Tags: apex, visualforce, rendered, apex-param, apexinputfile

Can someone please let me know what is my error here in the render condition?

```
rendered="{!IF(AND(Counting != 0,Inquiry=='Inquiry'),true,false)}"
```

Please note Inquiry is a param value set in apex page as below,

```
<apex:pageblocksection > 
          <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >  
                <apex:actionfunction name="Inquiry">    
                   <apex:outputText value="Written Inquiry/Referral" styleClass="pbtitle" />
                   <apex:commandbutton value="Add" action="{!Changecount}"/>
                     <apex:param name="Inquiry" assignto="{!Inquiry}" value="Inquiry"></apex:param>

                  </apex:actionfunction> 
               </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>  

        </apex:pageblocksection>  

        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Select Files" rendered="{!IF(AND(Counting != 0,Inquiry=='Inquiry'), true , false)}">  
            <apex:repeat value="{!allFileList}" var="AFL">  
                <apex:inputfile value="{!AFL.body}" filename="{!AFL.Name}"/> 
        </apex:repeat>  

      </apex:pageblocksection>
```

This param is assigned as below in controller,

```
 public String Inquiry {
        get;
        // *** setter is NOT being called ***
        set {
            Inquiry = value;
            System.debug('value: '+value);
 }
```

Can someone please tell me what is wrong here that Inquiry param value not getting set?

```
                  </apex:actionfunction> 
               </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Try change the name in the [apex:param](http://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_compref_param.htm) to something other than `Inquiry` as you already have that variable defined in your controller. Have you tried displaying the `Counting` and `Inquiry` variables on you page to see what values they contain?

Comment: The Inquiry value is not getting set with "Inquiry". Can you please suggest a wayout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set Inquiry value outside of the setter method. Maybe in a constructor of the controller.

Comment: It is getting error to define in a constructor.

Comment: Don't define in constructor. Only assign value to Inquiry in constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Use below instead,

```
rendered="{!AND(Counting != 0,Inquiry=='Inquiry')}"
```

Update property as below,

```
public String Inquiry {
                get;
                set {
                    Inquiry = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Inquiry');
                    System.debug('Inquiry : '+Inquiry);
         }
    }
```

Comment: Yes a better way !

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: No this was not the problem. problem is the value is not getting set by setter method. Can you please help here?

Comment: what does "value" mean in setter method?

Comment: It is the param value in page that I want to set.

Comment: m afraid its the wrong way..let me update the code..

Comment: Did the updated code work for u?

Comment: NO It throws this error:  Compile Error: expecting right curly bracket, found 'public

Comment: Please find the screenshot for the error , I shared with you in chat